# Android Custom Button Pressed State

Tags: android, custom-controls

I am trying to change the appearance of an Android Button, but I can't get it to work. I use this code in "custom_button.xml" to handle the drawing of the button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_normal"

   />

<item  android:drawable="@drawable/btn_over" 
    android:state_pressed="true"/>
```

In my layout file I set the button's background to the custom_button drawable. The normal state works (the one that first appears), but when the button is pressed the image doesn't change. I double checked to make sure I am using different images and I am. Does anyone know why this isn't working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Switch the order of the items (so pressed first, then neutral). Pressed or not, the top item is always true.